# How to debug php code in dreamweaver cs5?

Tags: php, ide, dreamweaver

If it doesn't support debugging are there any extensions or plugins out there?

Comment: what's wrong with var_dump() and die() ?

Comment: @Ben those are really a basic/poor solution, compared to what you can do with a debugger...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dreamweaver, even if it supports syntax-highlighting of PHP source, isn't quite known as a PHP-development environment ; so I'm not sure it supports debugging of PHP code.

Instead, I would recommend you use another more PHP-Oriented IDE, like :

- [**Eclipse PDT**](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project.php?id=tools.pdt) *(free -- not sure if it's maintained as much as it was a couple of month ago)*
- [**netbeans**](http://netbeans.org/features/php/) *(free)*
- [**PHPStorm**](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) *(not free)*

Those three all support debugging with the [**Xdebug**](http://xdebug.org/) extension.

Comment: No, Dreamweaver does not support  php debugging, i use PhpED for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You can use FirePHP with Firebug on any IDE including Dreamweaver. http://www.firephp.org/