# Chrome: HTML content inside PHP files not displaying when viewed as a local file

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, render, local

Prior to a recent update to Chrome, I was able to view a almost 95% HTML file locally that was saved as PHP but now with Chrome 67.0.3396.79 it appears this no longer works and instead always shows the source code instead of rendering whatever HTML it finds.

All files begin with the usual DOCTYPE html as expected, so it's the first thing the browser sees.

Previously I had this issue due to saving the PHP file as UTF-8 encoded. Re-saving as ANSI allowed Chrome to display it correctly, however now not even ANSI is working.

I do have a server set up and use it for development and testing in a real environment and the forms work as expected there. Sometimes editing locally is faster and easier for me, but I can use the server always if I must.

Was this an intended change or a new bug?

Comment: I suspect it was an intended change. It's been doing that for at least three months now. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213551/php-file-shows-code-in-chrome